# Change recipient and resend mail mistakenly sent to myself

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I already spent a lot of time composing an e-mail, stuffed it with attachments and then mistakenly sent it to myself.

Is there any way in Outlook to take this email and resend it to the right recipient without Re: and Fw:, without re-attaching all the files, without doing the monkey job?

It TheBat! I can do this easily in 20 seconds.

Comment: Can't you just re-send from your sent box? I don't use outlook, but resend is ctrl/D on my mailer, or in the 'messages' menu.

Comment: Tetsujin: I need to change recipient first.

Comment: Click on Forward and the Recipient box is ready for you to fill in.  It is an incredibly easy and simple task. Forward, Recipient, done. The subject will be the one in the first email you sent to yourself.

Comment: ↑ same for re-send. It just opens up the same 'un-sent' email & you can change your address. No need to even clear down the 'forwarding markup'.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an email with Attachments, Forward will keep the Attachments. Reply will not keep Attachments.

So just Forward the email to the correct person and it will just take a few seconds.

I Forward to keep attachments and Reply if I do not need to.

Comment: Forward adds forwarding markup, meaning you either send it with all that extra, or you have to manually clean it up first.

Comment: In Outlook for Windows, Forwarding includes the message and the attachments but does not add much else at all.

Comment: Still seems unnecessary work when there's a better function built-in. "When you forward a message, FW: appears at the beginning of the new message subject line. Also, in forwarded messages, the message body header information for the previous message appears, such as sender, date, and recipients."

Answer (score 1):

### Use Resend rather than Forward or Reply…

From [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/resend-an-email-message-acd16ac4-c881-477d-b4aa-36168fa96088)

> ## Resend an email message
>
> If one or more of the message
> recipients tell you that they didn't receive a message that you sent,
> you can use the Resend This Message command. The resend command can
> also be used to quickly send the message to new recipients.
>
> ### Resending vs. forwarding
>
> Using the resend command makes the new message appear the same as the original sent message — there’s no added
> information, unlike a forwarded message. When you forward a message,
> **FW:** appears at the beginning of the new message subject line. Also, in
> forwarded messages, the message body header information for the
> previous message appears, such as sender, date, and recipients.
>
> 1. In the folder pane, click **Sent Items**.
> 2. Double-click the message that you want to resend.
> 3. On the **Message** tab, in the **Move** group, click **Actions**, and then click **Resend This Message**.
>
> [image]
>
> A new message window opens. If there are multiple recipients, you can
> remove recipients who don’t need to receive the message again. Click
> the names that you want to remove, and then press Delete.
>
> > <sup>**Tip**: You can also add recipients who weren’t on the original message, add or remove attachments, and change the contents of the message.</sup>
>
> 4. Click **Send**.
>
> To resend multiple messages, repeat these instructions for each message. There isn’t a way to resend multiple messages at one
> time.